# Problem with custom Listview and Checkboxes/Buttons

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox, custom-controls

i´m in trouble with a custom Listview and (Checkboxes or Button). I follow a guide (the android devolopers´s cookbook) and my custom Listview show correctly. An visisble Error occured when selected Checkboxes are scrolling.(Wrong Checkboexes are checked)

I followed the guide on 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listviews_performance
but it doesn´t work.  How to save the state correctly?

Greeting 
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the checked items in a list variable (in your Adapter subclass) and set the correct state (checked/unchecked) depending upon whether the item is present in the list variable.

```
private List<MyItem> mCheckedItems; //In your adapter subclass
```

Add/remove an item from the list variable:

```
//The AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, is present where you set myListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
{

    MyItem item = myAdapter.getItem(position);
    myAdapter.updateCheckedItems(item);
}

public void updateCheckedItems(MyItem item) //In your adapter subclass
{
        if(!mCheckedItems.contains(item))
        {
            mCheckedItems.add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            mCheckedItems.remove(item);
        }
}
```

Set the correct state of the checkbox:

```
public View getView(int position , View view , ViewGroup parent) //In your adapter subclass
{
     final MyItem item = getItem(position);
     CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
     checkBox.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(item));
}
```

Comment: where i have to "implement OnItemClickListener" ? On the extended ArrayAdapter<?> class? The onItemClick Function never entered. And whats the doc Element you added?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry for being unclear. Please mark it as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: i can´t use onItemClick, because i use onItemListClick instead. The guide above show me the way for my answer. But Thanks.

Comment: Even if you are using `onItemListClick`, you can do-

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        MyItem item = myAdapter.getItem(position);
        myAdapter.updateCheckedItems(item);
    }